# Combined web/mobile development

Tags: asp.net, html, rest, mobile

I am starting a new app that will target both web and mobile (but possibly only as HTML5, not necessarily a native app)... So, what are the frameworks you guys recommend? I am familiar with plain ol' ASP.NET, and some minimum AJAX. So is it best, for example, to build a ASP.NET REST based API with a JQuery and JQueryMobile?

Comment: I am not aware of any framework other jquery mobile! About couple of years back when I had to create a small web app supporting both desktop & mobile, I had used ASP.NET web-forms with user-agent based sniffing to output CSS. Now, I will probably go with ASP.NET MVC. Also look at CSS 3 media queries - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/ & http://www.woothemes.com/2011/05/responsive-design-using-css3-media-queries/

Comment: what kind of web site, just text and images or interactive one like a web store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at a similar approach while we're commercializing an app of ours.

### Considerations

After 5 months of research and experience combined with the comments above, here are some considerations:

- Do you have control over your users' browser selection? If yes, HTML5 is a great and flexible. If your users are more up-to-date I would also recommend HTML5.
- The server-side framework in most cases will not matter, as long as you can develop a robust server with an efficient data model that's familiar and manageable.
- Are your mobile devices tablets or phones or both? If you are using phones it will be harder to fit and prioritize the interface.
- Do you know all of your app's functionality? This will be important for determining UX which will then help you understand how you will build out the client.
- Is your app real-time? And you have modern users? Websockets are handy. Here's a demo for ASP.NET http://wsaspnet.codeplex.com/

### Recommended Frameworks

Given your case, here are some recommended frameworks to make life easier:

- Stick with .NET on the server-side since you are familiar with it
- Use backbone.js to manage your client-side template
- HTML5 boilerplate is also worth a look http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile
- Use the latest JQuery library
- Use JQuery Mobile to adapt your HTML5 app to mobile devices
- There's also JQTouch http://www.jqtouch.com/
- Custom build your "fluid" javascript to adjust your client to different interfaces (I haven't been satisfied with current plugins and frameworks)
- If you are using websockets, web-socket-js is very handy for a flash fallback https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js ...otherwise stick with AJAX REST
- Consider PhoneGap to adapt your app if you need to distribute the app in approved marketplaces outside the browser http://phonegap.com/ and https://build.phonegap.com/
- Here's a C# Websocket server: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/c_sharp_web_socket_server.aspx

### Remember

Sometimes it is just necessary to build a separate client for mobile if your app is complex. It can be native, HTML5, or HTML5 put through PhoneGap.